# Error deserializing sexp from string

Tags: ocaml

I serialized the following ocaml record type using sexp

```
module User =
struct
  type id = int (*Uuid.t*) [@@deriving sexp]
module UserName =
struct
  type id = string [@@deriving sexp]
  type userId = {user_id: User.id} [@@deriving sexp]
  type eff = Add of userId | GetId [@@deriving sexp]
  let effToString x = Sexp.to_string (sexp_of_eff x)
  let stringToEff x = (*let y = string_before x 24 in 
                        eff_of_sexp (sexp_of_string (string_after y 1))*)
                      eff_of_sexp (Sexp.of_string x)
  let id_to_str x = x
end
```

An example sexp of the above record looks like `(Add((user_id 756438)))`

I converted the sexp to a string for embedding it in a json using

`let effToString x = (*Sexp.to_string_hum*) Sexp.to_string (sexp_of_eff x)`

I'm trying to deserialize the sexp string back to the record type using the following code

```
let stringToEff x = eff_of_sexp (sexp_of_string x)
```

I'm getting the error

`Fatal error: exception (Sexplib.Conv.Of_sexp_error
  (Failure "Microblog_app_runtime.UserName.eff_of_sexp: unexpected sum tag")
  "\"(Add((user_id 941952)))\"")`

I tried removing the escaped quotes but it still gives me the same error. Can someone please explain the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Sexp.of_string` instead of `sexp_of_string` for string parsing:

```
let stringToEff x = eff_of_sexp (Sexp.of_string x)
```

E.g.,

```
# effToString (Add {user_id = "941952"}) |> stringToEff;;
- : eff = Add {user_id = 941952}
```

There is a subtle difference between the two. The `Sexp.of_string` will parse an arbitrary string into a sexp data structure, while the `sexp_of_string` is a sexp representation of a string (i.e., an Atom), cf., `sexp_of_int`, `sexp_of_char`, etc.

Comment: try harder :) I did test it before the posting and it works, of course.

Comment: I think the issue is with {user_id = "941952"}. I edited the question to give more context. user_id is an integer field.  Can you try making this change?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine as it, I can go roundup, e.g., `UserName.effToString UserName.(Add {user_id = 941952}) |> UserName.stringToEff` and get no exceptions. The string representation looks like this: `"(Add((user_id 941952)))"`. Make sure, that you've updated your code, didn't forget to compile it, install it, and actually you're looking where you're looking.

Comment: If you don't believe me, then you can just copy-paste your own code into the toplevel and see it yourself :)